# Unable to upload images from Magento 1.9.0.1 admin for new products after update

Tags: magento-1.9

Initially I was facing an error "cannot read property 'checked' of undefined" but then I replaced the following code in gallery.phtml and now it's showing no error but now it's not showing the image after I click "Upload Files" and also not in database. I've checked the permissions too in Uploader.php and other server site settings.Unable to track the bug because it's showing no error in the console.However images are suucessfully uploaded to tmp folder and ajax is returning response 200 OK.One thing more I have also tried to use Dull Uploader but no success.

```
var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
```

Comment: is it possible to share url or share screen short of this?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Jinesh but I've able to resolve it by replacing the js folder from fesh Magento 1.9.0.1 and changing the code in gallery.phtml file from a patch.It is working  now.